# Is there a modification of this that can make the form value appear?

Tags: javascript, exploit

So, here's the form

```
<form action="/missions/basic/3/index.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="file" value="password.php" />
<input type="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
<input type=button value="Get Value" onclick="printIt()" /></form>
```

I have these methods here to try to get the value to appear.

```
function printIt(){
   for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('password').length; i++) {
       var x = window.alert(document.getElementsByName('password')[i].value());
       window.alert(x);
   }
}
```

I want to know what I can change in those last two methods to get the value to appear.

Answer (score 1):

The function `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an array, not one element, so changing your code to `window.alert(document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value);` should get the first item's value. The first item will most likely be the element in your form you're looking for.

Comment: The challenge is to get the right password. What you put just answers how to get whatever I type in in plain text.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the "right" password?

Comment: There's a hidden form value that I need to enter to be able to move onto the next challenge. I need a function that would make it appear, not knowing what it is.

Comment: The only really "hidden" form value is the input with type hidden, you can find that by doing the same function as before except looking for an element with the name "file" instead of the name "password". Also if you are talking about just making it appear, run this: `function printIt(){
   for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('password').length; i++) {
       document.getElementsByName('password')[i].setAttribute('type','text');
       
   }
}`